# String.split(String regex) Symbol avoidance

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have

```
String text2 = "Samaras did something by Papandreou's government.";
```

When I use

```
String[] w2 = text2.split("\\s+");
```

it takes the "Papandreou's" as a whole word (as its supposed to do). But how can I avoid the `'s` after the word?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid"? It's not clear what you want the output to be.

Comment: you can further apply `w2[4].substring(0,w2[4].indexOf("'"))` on this

Comment: I want to use that word as it is for another purpose. Just without the 's

Comment: Then include that `'s` as part of delimiter. You can make it optional with `?` metacharacter. For now it looks like you are looking for `split("('s)?\\s+")`, but something tells me that you will find some other problem soon and then you will describe what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Well that will do for now thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text2.split("(\\'s)?\\s+");
```

This regular expression splits the ***'s*** as optional, so it means either **"Split 's follow with spaces"** or **"Split only spaces"**.

Comment: `'` is not regex metacharacter, so there is no need to escape it, unless you are intentionally trying to obfuscate your code a little, or confuse someone who will maintain it.